# Sending data to a slow API without slowing down page load

Tags: php

I am doing a curl call to pass information to an API.  The issue I am having is sometimes the API responds slowly.  I need to immediately pass the data, but I don't want the user to be stuck on the processing page while the API tries to make the connection.

Is there a good alternative, kind of like multithreading or something that I could use to still query this API while moving the user onto the next page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fire-and-forget.

I don't know if CURL can do this but make it so it wont attempt to *read* from the stream. Just send and close.

If the connection to the remote site is slow as well you'll need to do some proxying.

Fire-and-forget proxying is a poor man's solution to threading.

Comment: Fire-and-forget using fsockopen did what I was looking for.  Thanks!